# NodeJS sequelize and sqlite error: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm in the process of learning how to use NodeJS using express it's minimalistic web framework. I've also added sequelize an ORM and sqlite.
The project folder name is `expressapp` so in the root directory I've created a models file using sqlite

## models.js

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const db = new Sequelize({
  dialect: "sqlite",
  storage: "./db.sqlite"
});

const User = db.define("user", {
  username: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  loggedIn: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN }
});

const Messages = db.define("messages", {
    public: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN },
    to: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    messsage: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN },
    createdBy: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE }
})

db.sync();

module.exports = db;
```

inside it's route file `routes\index.js` I've imported the model and try to check if a username exists (for now with a static text) before deciding if I should add the username to the list.

## index.js

```
var express = require('express');
const models = require("./../models");

var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/login-ajax', function (req, res) {
  //assume the front end ensured there's valid post data
  let existing = models.user.findAll({
    where: {
        username: 'ME'
    }
  });

  res.send('Post data received')
})

module.exports = router;
```

On loading this is the message on the terminal from nodejs which seems to indicate things are working ok.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www expressapp`
Tue, 03 Jul 2018 06:03:33 GMT sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators at node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:242:13
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `username` VARCHAR(255), `loggedIn` TINYINT(1), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`users`)
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `public` TINYINT(1), `to` VARCHAR(255), `messsage` TINYINT(1), `createdBy` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`messages`)
```

I then on the console from the browser check to see if there's a bug with a post request using

```
$.post("/login-ajax", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Then I get back the error `Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined` and a 500 response error.

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the "model.user" object. Are you sure that is existing? It's only a hunch but you can check that.

Comment: According to another stackoverflow post I found they suggest you should use the name used in the `db.define("user"` not the const name `User` anyway both crash the same

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you imported your model correctly ?

**If your project structure looks like this:**

```
root
- models.js
- routes
- - index.js
```

And you want to import models.js inside index.js, then you need to use:

```
const models = require('../models');
```

( or at least try because you will find different approaches around the web when it comes to importing local modules )

**Or you just use quick and dirty console.log(models); to see if it got imported correcty and to see if it is defined and not undefined**

```
const models = require('./../models');
console.log(models);
```

Comment: don't think the import is the issue, I started with the `require('../models');` anyway here's a gist of using the first method https://gist.github.com/Six-wars/6a9e5a3ad7fea78b3de6dc956a9aa56a and the second method https://gist.github.com/Six-wars/93e310dd6c31d3297b4f2b6c3c558164

Comment: Have you tried logging the complete models Object to the console for troubleshooting ? E.g. with console.dir(models,{depth:null});

Comment: it's the same thing, some jargon of text and a final result of `undefined`

Comment: Then A it's not imported correctly or B the creation of const db is somehow wrong. Try logging db inside models.js and see everything gets created the way it should.